# how do i recover broken install?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I was trying to install nvidia cuda support with the OEM drivers, and black listing neavou, upon reboot, I can only gain a graphical session using Ubuntu Wayland using gdm3. I undid the changes I know I made, and removed the blacklisting of noeavuo. this did not fix my computer though.

I can also login via the terminal. I tried a variety of things to startx, but persistently it just seems to hang up. Im not sure what to do. I only installed gdm3 to gain access to the wayland interface, lightdm also was crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did to recover:
`sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg`
this has the side effect of removing ubuntu-mate-core, which is hey, I need that. 
then:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg ubuntu-mate-core`

then

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

when I rebooted, I was then able to select the Mate session, and everything appears to be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the history command, it should show you what was processed that you might need to roll back. Other than that, check log files and

```
dmesg |tail
```

or so.

Welcome to the club, we've all been there at one point or another.